# Can i create an events or triggers in RedShift, if can how

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm  trying to create events in RedShift like I do in MySQL.

create events my_event ...;

Does Redshift support in events and triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Amazon Redshift does not currently support events or triggers.

The [(SDD414) Amazon Redshift Deep Dive and What's Next](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/sdd414-amazon-redshift-deep-dive-and-whats-next-aws-reinvent-2014) presentation at AWS re:Invent in 2014 mentioned User-Defined Functions (slide 19), but this is unlikely to include events/triggers.

[image: User Defined Functions]